# child thread to parent thread communication

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am working on a java multi-threaded application on Android.

Thread 1: Listener Thread.
keep listening on a socket, fires 2nd thread for some action

Thread 2: Action Thread.
short lived. get fired from first thread, do a simple action and dies.

Thread 1 does not wait on Thread 2, as it goes back to listening after firing Thread 2.

Can I execute a method in Thread1 (say thread2ActionCompleted()) from Thread2 just before it ends.

For some reason I cannot use static method or static variable in Thread 1

I saw some similar threads using `ExecutorService`, but couldn't find a good example if it will work in my situation.

Comment: Please edit your question and associated tags with the language you are asking about.

Comment: Just pass a reference to Thread1 to Thread2.

Comment: Nah, you're using `Android`. FYI, you should edit the tags instead of commenting. It is always desired that the OP update the question with more information and not sprinkle it in comments.

Comment: Once upon I already answered similar question, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13934591/1891118 , there is sample with ```Executor```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looke like your problem is simple enough, here is pseudo code.

```
Thread1 {

 run() {
    //check condition
    //If condition meets create Thread Thread2
    //set parent in Thread2
    //start Thread2
 }

  Method m1 {

  }
}
```

Thread1 keep running, you can start thread 2 base on your condition.

```
Thread2 {
   Thread1 parent;
   //When done call parent.m1
}
```

Cheers !!

Comment: I want to know when thread2 completes in thread1 and call some post-processing method in thread1.

Comment: How do I pass flagDone from thread1. I do not want thread1 to keep check if thread2 is done. thread2 should call a post-processing method in thread1 once its done.

Comment: @ajitk - This could be done in so many ways, but have edited pseudocode again, trying to keep it simple.

Comment: Sachin - I cannot create a second instance of Thread1. Thread1 is continuously listening for events on an established communication channel (Socket Stream to a C++ module). Sharing this channel will open up more synchronization issues.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update: 
I ended up passing parent thread instance as a parameter to the constructor of child thread. Worked like a charm and any code that I wanted to be access only once at a time, I put in synchronize block.

```
Parent Thread: Thread1
Child Thread: Thread2

class Thread1 extends Thread implements Runnable {
  ...
  Thread2 t2 = new Thread2(this);
  new Thread(t2, "ChildThread").start();
  ...
}

class Thread2 extends Thread implements Runnable {
 ...
 Thread1 t1;
 Thread2 (Thread1 t) {
   t1 = t;
 }
 ...
 t1.CallAnyMethod();
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a potential candidate for an implementation of the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Thread 2 would be able to notify all of its observers (in particular, Thread 1) when it is finished doing it's work.

For example:

Thread 1 implements Observer.

Thread 2 implements Observable.

When thread 2 finishes, it notifies all observers that it has finished. This would tell thread 1 that thread 2 is done.

Comment: I would encourage you to look at the sample that Wikipedia provides. It is a relatively straight forward implementation of the pattern.

Comment: Observable is not an interface. Hence this will not work in my case. (This is the error I get: The type Observable cannot be a superinterface of Thread1.java; a superinterface must be an interface). 

This basically means a Thread cannot be Observable. It can be an Observer though.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is a `Future`. Basically, `thread2` will place its result an a thread-safe holder object which is shared with `thread1`. When `thread1` wants to know what happened with `thread2` it can check the `Future` object.

This could be accomplished using a `ExecutorService` to manage thread2's lifecycle and [submitting a `Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29) to the `ExecutorService`.

Comment: Sounds good. I am going to explore this option and will let you know if it works for me.